# Python function to check if credit card number is a valid number using for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

So this is a cs assignment, and I wrote code that works for 2 out of the 9 test cases (which are unknown), but I don't know why it won't work/pass any other ones. I understand I should try to figure out how to do this on my own, and I have tried, but I am really lost and need help!

"Write a file named credit_card.py containing a single function, check. Check accepts a single input – a positive integer. It returns True if the integer represents a valid credit card number. As with all functions that return a bool value, if it does not return True it should return False.

Credit card numbers have what is called a check digit. This is a simple way of detecting common mis-typings of card numbers. The algorithm is as follows:

Form a sum of every other digit, including the right-most digit; so 5490123456789128 (5490123456789128) sums to 4 + 0 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 1 + 8 = 33.
Double each remaining digit, then sum all the digits that creates it; the remaining digits (5 9 1 3 5 7 9 2) in our example (5490123456789128) double to 10 18 2 6 10 14 18 4, which sums to 1+0 + 1+8 + 2 + 6 + 1+0 + 1+4 + 1+8 + 4 = 37
Add the two sums above (33 + 37 = 70)
If the result is a multiple of 10 (i.e., its last digit is 0) then it was a valid credit card number."

```
def check(x):
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 0
    if x < 0:
        return False
    for i in str(x) [1::2]:
        num1 += int(i)
        return num1
    for i in str(x) [0::2]:
        num2 += int(int(i * 2) % 10) + int(int(i * 2) / 10)
        return num2
    check_digit = num1 + num2
    if check_digit % 10 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You have intermediate returns.  Doubt that will work.

Comment: Why are you returning the `num1`  and `num2` in your loops ?

Comment: more like: `num1 = sum(int(i) for i in str(x) [1::2])`
and `num2 = sum(int(int(i * 2) % 10) + int(int(i * 2) / 10) for i in str(x) [0::2])`

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(x):
    if x[0] == '-':     # x is [str], "x < 0" is wrong
        return False
    try:
        nums = map(int, x)
    except Exception:
        return False

    sum1 = 0
    sum2 = 0
    for i in nums[1::2]:
        sum1 += int(i)
    for i in nums[0::2]:
        sum2 += ((i * 2) % 10 + (i * 2) / 10)   # i is [str], "i * 2" is wrong
    check_digit = sum1 + sum2
    if check_digit % 10 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```